# Salesforce flow variable User.Id not printing out the full User Id

Tags: visual-workflow

I am trying to update the owner of the case if the running user is different from the case owner. I do a Get_case_record and get the case owner and do a decision check with the running user Id, what I see is the flow variable User.Id got rid of the last three chars in the Id.

This is what I get when I print out the values

```
Case Owner Id which I retrieved from the Get Case Record call - 005410000078IzlAAE
Flow Variable User.Id - 005410000078Izl - **here the last three chars are missing**
```

Please advise.

Comment: you don't need the last 3 chars

Comment: But my decision in the flow is not taking the right path in the flow just because of this issue.

Comment: But why would your flow be testing against hard-coded Ids?  You should be querying for Ids or getting from CMDT or Custom Labels; you can also exploit Formula function `CASESAFEID` to get an 18 char Id

Comment: @cropredy I was not hardcoding ids, I was using the user.id flow variable and case.ownerId from the get case record call. That formula worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conversion between 15- and 18-character Ids should generally always work, but sometimes weird things happen. The easiest solution would be to add a formula to fix this. Click on the Manager tab, click New Resource, choose the Formula resource type, use the Text return type, and enter the following formula: `CASESAFEID($User.Id)`. You can use this to get a guaranteed 18-character Id in your formula.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox,